# Async, await and Task works in debug mode only

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

The code below begins with the first line calling 'LoadNames' from a .net page. If I'm not in debug mode the interviews variable is set to null. If I add a debug point there and step through it gets a value from the api.

It was getting interviews in UAT. I'm pointing it now at LIVE.

I'm thinking it's likely something unresolved asynchronously. The old api being slower probably made it appear like it was working, and adding debug will slow it down making it appear correct too.

```
Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadNames));

private async Task LoadNames()
{
   VideoInterviewRepository videoRepository = await Repository.CreateClient();
   IEnumerable<Api> interviews = await Repository.GetEntityList<Api>(EndPoints);

   CODE HERE RUNS BUT FAILS BECAUSE THE ABOVE CODE RETURNS NULL
   var interviewList = interviews.ToDictionary(o => o.id, o => o.name);
}


public static Task<VideoInterviewRepository> CreateClient()
{
    var videoInterviewRepository = new VideoInterviewRepository();
    return videoInterviewRepository.InitializeClient();
}
private async Task<VideoInterviewRepository> InitializeClient()
{
    client = VideoInterviewHttpClient.GetClient(VideoInterviewEndPoints.baseUrl);

    var bearer = await Authenticate.GetBearerTokenAsync(client);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearer);

    return this;
}
public static async Task<string> GetBearerTokenAsync(HttpClient client)
{
   var bearerResult = await client.SendAsync(requestToken);
   var bearerData = await bearerResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

   bearerToken = JObject.Parse(bearerData)["access_token"].ToString();
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetEntityList<T>(string path)
{
    IEnumerable<T> model = await GetAndParseApiResponse<IEnumerable<T>>(path);
    return model;
}

private async Task<T> GetAndParseApiResponse<T>(string path)
{
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      model = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<T>(content, model);
   }

   return model;
}
```

Comment: "not working" means what exactly? You need to give far more detail here.

Comment: While you are "stepping through", all threads are paused. If any thread was still running, there would be no way to get accurate data taht actually stay accurate until your brain has processed it. Stepping through and Garbage Collection are two of the rare cases where no multithreading in the app domain can work.

Comment: Notice a missing async in the CreateClient signature.

Comment: When I say 'Not working' I mean the code isn't run - I'm not getting the content from the api call. However, as soon as i add a debug point, then play it runs

Comment: I added the missing async and corresponding await but same error.

Comment: @KingoftheNorth: There is nothing wrong with that; it just returns a `Task`.

Comment: `GetAndParseApiResponse` doesn't always return a value. Are you sure this relates to async and isn't just that you're getting back a null value?

Comment: GetBearerTokenAsync() won't even compile, due to missing return.

Comment: GetAndParseApiResponse should always return a value. It always did in UAT and always does when I step through.

Comment: Sometimes, the best way to see how your application is behaving is to add logs in the methods to know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug! All the async and awaits and Tasks were correct. The 3rd party didn't register the token on their end fast enough which is why by stepping through I caused a delay. I should have handled response.IsSuccessStatusCode.