# EF Core: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I appreciate this question has been asked. But I seem to have done what people are suggesting to fix it and I am still having the same issue. I can't see where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am getting the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context
> before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by
> different threads using the same instance of DbContext

In these specific areas:

```
return await _dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
var editPost = await _postRepository.GetByIdAsync(postModel.Id); 
await _postAppService.Update(mapped);
await _postPageService.UpdatePost(Post);
```

Here is my code:

> Just to add a bit more detail. I will list the exact steps:

> First I select the post I would like to edit. The following gets called:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? postId)
        {
            if (postId == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Post = await _postPageService.GetPostById(postId.Value);
            if (Post == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }                   
            return Page();
        }

public async Task<PostViewModel> GetPostById(int postId)
        {
            var post = await _postAppService.GetPostById(postId);
            
            var mapped = _mapper.Map<PostViewModel>(post);

            return mapped;
        }

public async Task<PostModel> GetPostById(int postId)
        {
            var post = await _postRepository.GetByIdAsync(postId);
            var mapped = ObjectMapper.Mapper.Map<PostModel>(post);
            return  mapped;
        }



  public virtual async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
        }
```

> I then make my changes and click the update button:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }
        try
    {
        await _postPageService.UpdatePost(Post);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!PostExists(Post.Id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}

public async Task UpdatePost(PostViewModel postViewModel)
{        
    var mapped = _mapper.Map<PostModel>(postViewModel);
    
    if (mapped == null)
        throw new Exception($"Entity could not be mapped.");
        await _postAppService.Update(mapped);
    _logger.LogInformation($"Entity successfully added - IndexPageService");
}

public async Task Update(PostModel postModel)
{
    ValidatePostIfNotExist(postModel);
        var editPost = await _postRepository.GetByIdAsync(postModel.Id);
    if (editPost == null)
        throw new ApplicationException($"Entity could not be loaded.");
        ObjectMapper.Mapper.Map<PostModel, Post>(postModel, editPost);
        await _postRepository.UpdateAsync(editPost);
    _logger.LogInformation($"Entity successfully updated - AspnetRunAppService");
}

public async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
{
    _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I have also set the lifetime of my `DbContext` to `Transient`.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyJourneyContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("MyJourneyConnectionString")),
                                        ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

So I am using `await` and have set the lifetime of my `DbContext` to `Transient`. But I am clearly still doing something wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You should use Scoped Life Time. Transient LifeTime create a new Databasecontext each time you call it but scoped life time create Databasecontext per http request.

Comment: Do you mean as follows: services.AddDbContext<MyJourneyContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("MyJourneyConnectionString")), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);  I am still getting the same error

Comment: AddDbContext uses Scoped by default, which is typically the best choice, but using Transient should also work, and won't cause that error.  There's not enough information here to tell where you're using a DbContext instance from multiple threads.  Try to simplify the scenario down to the point where you can post a complete repro.

Comment: Hi David, I have added a bit more detail by listing the steps I have taken which lead to the error. Does this help any?

Comment: Can you perhaps identify at which point the error gets thrown? Does it get thrown when you save a post or when you get a post? because based on the methods you provided above, there isn't one method where you tend to perform two operations within the same method. It is also worth noting that Non Async Methods(non task returning) aren't treated asynchronously even if you call them with `await` when you call them.

Comment: It gets thrown when I  update the post.    It seems to throw the error here: public async Task UpdatePost(PostViewModel postViewModel)
        {
            
            var mapped = _mapper.Map<PostModel>(postViewModel);
            
            if (mapped == null)
                throw new Exception($"Entity could not be mapped.");

            await _postAppService.Update(mapped);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Entity successfully added - IndexPageService");
        }

Comment: However when I place breakpoints in all the areas it is suppose to hit. It hits them and works. If i let it run without these, it fails

Comment: Remove `ServiceLifetime.Transient` from your code. Use only `services.AddDbContext<MyJourneyContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("MyJourneyConnectionString")));` and let us know if your code is working.

Comment: @atiyar still not working. It seems to be this method causing the issue:            `public virtual async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id); }`                                                                                                                   When I put a break point on it, it gets hit twice at once but works. When I remove the break point from this method however, and let it run I get the errors mentioned in the original post. Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: @insanepaul I see you had a similar issue. But not sure what your fix means. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985611/async-await-and-task-works-in-debug-mode-only] Can you help with this?

Comment: Hi all. I fixed this. I had validation that was being called inside the `Update` method. It too was using `_postRepository.GetByIdAsync(postModel.Id);`. Thank you all for your help.